# Display text on link hover that has a negative text indent

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover, sprite

I'd like to be able to hover over an href (which has a background image and a negative text indent) and display a line of text underneath in a separate div.

I've found tutorials for show/hide in css and jquery but they won't work because I have the text hidden due to the -99999em text indent.

Basically I have used a sprite in a ul to display 11 cars in a row, when you hover the car/link the sprite changes to another color of car to show it's being selected. I'd like there to be a description for each car/link below the row of cars that shows up when you hover over each car. example: http://jsfiddle.net/a7nDn/

```
<section id="brandSearch">
    <ul id="car-nav">
    <li id="car-01"><a href="#">小型车</a></li>
    <li id="car-02"><a href="#">小型车</a></li>
    <li id="car-03"><a href="#">家用车</a></li>
    <li id="car-04"><a href="#">家用车</a></li>
    <li id="car-05"><a href="#">豪华车</a></li>
    <li id="car-06"><a href="#">豪华车</a></li>
    <li id="car-07"><a href="#">跑车</a></li>
    <li id="car-08"><a href="#">SUV</a></li>
    <li id="car-09"><a href="#">SUV</a></li>
    <li id="car-10"><a href="#">SUV</a></li>
    <li id="car-11"><a href="#">皮卡</a></li>
    </ul>


    </section><!--end brandSearch-->
```

CSS

```
#brandSearch {
    padding-top: 35px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px 1px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.10);
    webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px 1px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.10);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 8px 1px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.10);
    background-image: url(../images/megaphone.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
}
#car-nav {
    width: 920px;
    height: 123px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    padding: 0;
    background-image: url(../images/carNav.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position:relative;
}
#car-nav li, #car-nav a {
    height: 123px;
    display: block;
}
#car-nav li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    text-indent: -9999em;
}
#car-01 { width: 90px; }
#car-02 { width: 90px; }
#car-03 { width: 90px; }
#car-04 { width: 90px; }
#car-05 { width: 90px; }
#car-06 { width: 90px; }
#car-07 { width: 80px; }
#car-08 { width: 80px; }
#car-09 { width: 70px; }
#car-10 { width: 70px; }
#car-11 { width: 80px; }
#car-01 a:hover { background: url(../images/carsHover.jpg) no-repeat 0px -0px;}
#car-02 a:hover { background:url(../images/carsHover.jpg) -90px 0px no-repeat; }
#car-03 a:hover { background:url(../images/carsHover.jpg) -180px 0px no-repeat; }
#car-04 a:hover { background:url(../images/carsHover.jpg) -270px -0px no-repeat; }
#car-05 a:hover { background:url(../images/carsHover.jpg) -360px -0px no-repeat; }
#car-06 a:hover { background:url(../images/carsHover.jpg) -450px -0px no-repeat; }
#car-07 a:hover { background:url(../images/carsHover.jpg) -540px -0px no-repeat; }
#car-08 a:hover { background:url(../images/carsHover.jpg) -620px -0px no-repeat; }
#car-09 a:hover { background:url(../images/carsHover.jpg) -700px -0px no-repeat; }
#car-10 a:hover { background:url(../images/carsHover.jpg) -770px -0px no-repeat; }
#car-11 a:hover { background:url(../images/carsHover.jpg) -840px -0px no-repeat; }
```

Comment: Have a demo for us? Where is your jQuery?

Comment: I can help you but you need to build a codepen or jsfiddle for us all. Your images wont work since they are local.

Comment: @ZachSaucier No jquery at the moment.. Here is a demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/a7nDn/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put car description div inside each anchor and display it when hover.

EDIT: you need to set the style of the span to make it visible in within your anchor

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/a7nDn/19/

HTML

```
<li id="car-01"><a href="#">小型车<span class="desc">car 01 is very good</span></a></li>
```

CSS

```
#car-nav li a span {
border: 1px solid lime;
text-indent: 0em;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left:0px;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
display: none;
}

#car-nav li a:hover span {
display: block;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't appear to work and I think it's because all text is at a negative indent so the link will work with a background img

Comment: Added some styles to display a box with the text within the anchor

Answer (score 0):

Here are 4 different solutions, none of them require any changes to your HTML, all of them except the 4th (last) require you remove `text-indent` from `#car-nav li`. The 3rd and 4th solutions only require minimal CSS additions.

---

I've hid the values originally using `display:none` on `#car-nav>li>a` instead of `text-indent` on `#car-nav li` **(Please note you'll need to remove `text-indent`)**. Then I show them when hovered: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a7nDn/1/)

```
$('#car-nav li').hover(function () {
    $(this).children('a').show();
});
```

---

If you want to hide them after it is done hovering, you can add that: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a7nDn/4/)

```
$('#car-nav li').hover(function () {
    $(this).children('a').show();
}, function() {
    $(this).children('a').hide();
});
```

---

the second way is also possible with pure css, like this: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a7nDn/18/)

```
#car-nav li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
}
#car-nav>li>a {
    display:none;
}
#car-nav>li:hover a {
    display:block;
}
```

---

If you really want to use `text-indent` you could just add this: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a7nDn/20/)

```
#car-nav>li:hover {
    text-indent: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! that is what I was looking for, just wondering if you know why when I change the position so it sits under the row of cars it all of the sudden doesn't show the cursor finger or show the hover color change. Other than positioning is there another way to display the text under the image?

Comment: Hey @saraht, the bottom 2 solutions change the hover color. Is this what you are looking for? Otherwise, could you show an image or something to show what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks @smerny they did work exactly as I wanted but I wanted to move the text below but something weird would happen when I did that. With another person's suggestion found a way to make it all work. Thanks again :)